# Increase model integer field according to repetition of words

Tags: python, django, string, forms, models

Let's say I have two models, a Box model and a Thing model. The last one has Box as a Foreign Key. Each Box works as a container of string objects the user can add using a ModelForm. The models.py should be something like this:

**models.py**

```
class Box(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=120, unique=True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.name

class Things(models.Model):
    box = models.ForeignKey(Box)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    thing_number = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=1)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Now, for each time a user insert the same string into the Form, I'd like to increase the "thing_number" Integer field by 1. Is there an easy way to do so?

Comment: You should do that in your `forms.py` file. Could your please share your `forms.py`?

Comment: why do you need this? What's wrong with the PK?

Comment: Nothing wrong at all, but since a change of a model field depends on a form input, IMO I would include that "increment action" inside the `clean_name` method.

Comment: But why? you are storing redundant and possibly inaccurate data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should make the field `thing_number` of `Thing` default to zero.
If you do this, then you can increase the Thing number by

```
thing, created = Things.objects.get_or_create(box=your_box, name=thing_name)
thing.things_number += 1
thing.save()
```

other wise:

```
thing, created = Things.objects.get_or_create(box=your_box, name=thing_name,
                                              default={'thing_number':0})
thing.things_number += 1
thing.save()
```

---- extra

As @e4c5 said the code above may cause race condition, then the code can be change like this:

```
Things.objects.get_or_create(box=your_box, name=thing_name, default={'thing_number':0})
Things.objects.filter(box=your_box, name=thing_name).update(thing_number=F('thing_number') + 1)
```

Comment: This leads to race conditions

Comment: Answer has been changed according your advice. Thx

Comment: Then you should keep there is only one `Thing` has same name for every Box. For you, you should add a unique key in database for Thing with (`name`, `box_id`) columns